# Creating different objects in inheritance java

Tags: java, object, oop, inheritance, instance

I am thinking about this java oop problem . I don't exactly know exactly what is really happening there . Can someone make me understand ?

```
abstract class A {
    public int proc (A p){
        return 98;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int proc(A p) {
        return 17;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public int proc (C p) {
        return 65;
    }
} 

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        C x = new C(); // here x is C type and is an instance of C ?
        A y=new B();  // here y is A type and is an instance of B?
        C z=new C();  // here z is C type and is an instance of C ?
        System.out.println(y.proc(x)+z.proc(x)); /* y is A type so it is looking for proc function  in A ,but doesn't return 98 
, z is C type and it is looking for proc function in C and return 65 .*/
        
     }
}
```

Can someone tell me how should I tackle theese instances ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the abstract class here is bad. Abstract classes mainly help with code reuse. A classic example in Java is the `AbstractCollection` that implements what methods it can. It might implement `constains` with a default of checking if an object equals any in the collection. If a collection has a better algorithm, it can override that and implement something else. Since `proc` is overridden in every implementation of `A`, there is no code reuse and it indicates an interface, which only makes promises about an API, might be better suited for this situation.

Comment: Overriding methods is a common source of error although its benefits of code reuse often make doing so warranted. It's common to annotate overridden methods with `@Override` to help reduce these bugs. An annotation labels something like a method with metainformation. In its most basic use, it doesn't change the way the code executes. It's much like a comment except more advanced techniques (such as reflection) can do particular things if they see particular annotations. Annotations make their way into the compiled code unlike comments.

Comment: Oh, I'm noticing now that `C::proc` doesn't override `A::proc` since its `proc` takes `C` instead of `A`. While it's not a good idea to make such similar method signatures, that does make the use of abstract class here actually give us some code reuse. `C` has the default implementation of `proc` that takes `A` as well as the one that takes a `C` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Y is an A but contains a reference to a B so when we call y.proc it is the proc in B that is called, and returns 17, not 98.
You need to look at the instance that is created and not the type of variable.

Comment: And what about the fucntions parameters ? For exemple if in the B class ,proc function would have been (B p) as parameter z.proc(x) returns 98 . How parameters affect the program running ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can create base class objects which hold the child classes objects except for abstract classes.

*A is an abstract class, you cannot instantiate it, but you can assign an object of the child class to it which holds the child class object's features.*

You can think, we are assigning the reference of B to y which has a type of A.

```js
System.out.println(y.proc(x));
```

The code above will print 17, which is the return value of the proc in class B returns.

Whenever you call the methods of y, the compiler will give you class B's methods automatically.
So, you are creating an instance of class B in the memory and assigning it to y which points to the same memory location.
For that reason, you can use the methods of class B.
Same goes for z as well.

Comment: What about functions parameter ? How can they influence the output ?

Comment: @fast539 In your example, `A` has a default implementation of `proc` that takes one argument of type `A`. `B` overrides that implementation. `C` has both the default implementation defined in `A` (if you pass `A` into `proc`) as well as a new definition of `proc` that takes `C` as an argument. The way the code decides is it tries to use the most specific type possible as there is ambiguity with `C` being an `A`. For example, `f(new Object())` and `f(new Integer(5))` will call `void f(Object o)` and `void f(Integer i)` respectively if both functions exist. Note, `Integer` is an `Object`.